# int to binary function without recursion?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I want to display my decimal number as bits.

```
int g = 2323;

for (int i = 31; i>=0; i--) // int has 32 bits
{
    Console.Write(((g >> 1) & 1) == 1 ? "1" : "0"); // shift right 1 and display it
    g = g / 2; // shift right= divide by 2
}
```

However this display the number like mirror  ( 12345 -> 54321)

I could shift left from the left but then  : I might get exception ..(too big number)

What should i need to change in my code to display it correct but :

1. no convert(...) method
2. no insertion to middleman array
3. no recursion.

Is there anything ?

Comment: Any particular reason why the first two constraints are necessary or in fact sensible?

Comment: Convert  : I want to do bit operation myself. middleman : Not very smart + cost performance.

Comment: Why no convert method (i.e., var binary = Convert.ToString(2323, 2);). It is going to be the simplest and cleanest approach?

Comment: @CalgaryCoder  I want to do bit operation myself.

Comment: Why? Console.Write(Convert.ToString(g,2))...

Comment: Why all the other constraints then? While call Console.Writeline for every bit, instead of whapping the result in stringbuilder and then writing the result reversed. Smacks of premature optimisation this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert binary to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278377/how-to-convert-binary-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just off the top of my head:

```
int g = 2323;

for (uint mask = 0x80000000; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
    Console.Write(((uint)g & mask) != 0 ? "1" : "0");
```

Comment: is it because 0x8000000 = 2147483648 which is (int.max +1 ) ?

Comment: I used because in binary it is a one followed by 31 zeroes.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I used a uint so that the >>= operator would do a logical right shift (no sign extension) instead of an arithmetic right shift.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to simplify the code.

```
string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 32).Select(i => (num >> (31 - i) & 1).ToString()))
```

Comment: Cool use of LINQ, but it seems to violate the spirit of constraint #2 (no middleman array). You are creating a number of 1-character strings and then joining them to form a final string.

Comment: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: @RoyiNamir: what version of .NET are you using? The code passed the test on .NET 4. If you are using lower version, adding `.ToArray()` to the end of the `.ToString())` will eliminate the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shifting the number, shift a mask.  Start at 0x80000000 and  & it with the number.  Non-zero result = '1'. Shift the mask right 31 times to examine all the bit positions.

Comment: , sample   ? (peace of sample)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: why should he write your code? The description is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to yours, but it checks the most significant bit (masked by `0x80000000`, corresponding to `10000000000000000000000000000000` in binary), rather than the least significant bit (masked by `1`).

```
uint g = 2323;

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    Console.Write((g & 0x80000000) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
    g <<= 1;
}
```

Use the following variation to eliminate leading zeros:

```
uint g = 2323;
bool isSignificant = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    bool isZero = (g & 0x80000000) == 0;

    if (!isZero)
        isSignificant = true;

    if (isSignificant)
        Console.Write(isZero ? "0" : "1");

    g <<= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going left to right, so they're printed left to right :)

You can create a mask with 1 in MSB and right-shift it 1-bit every iteration (don't forget to make the mask `unsigned`).

The mask can be created by shifting a 1 to the left 32 bits, like

```
unsigned int mask = 1 << 32;
```

Now you can shift it 1 bit to the left each time:

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    Console.Write((g & mask == 0) ? "0" : "1");
    mask >>= 1;
}
```

**Note:** The `mask` must be unsigned, otherwise whenever you apply right-shift on it, the MSB/sign bit (which is 1) will be successively copied to the bits to the left.

However, you won't have this requirement it if you *create* the mask every time:

```
for(i = 31; i >= 0; i++)
{
    Console.Write((g & (1 << i) == 0) ? "0" : "1");
    mask >>= 1;
}
```

This loop is similar to the loop in your code.